# "Nobody but him was present." or "Nobody but he was present."

Tags: pronouns

> 1. Nobody but **him** was present.
> 2. Nobody but **he** was present.

Which is the correct usage and why?

Comment: @Robusto I looked at that but I do not think it has a good explanation.

Comment: "Nobody was present but he" vs "Nobody was present but him" is perhaps an easier version to look at. In the versions you have, I would use "but him"

Comment: As long as the pronoun isn't  the first and only subject NP, the objective  form is right. _Him_ is part of the phrase _Nobody but him_, which is a variant of _nobody, except for him_, so you see where the _him_ comes from. This is a special idiomatic use of _but_, like its use in [_Nobbut_-Clefts](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Nobbut.pdf),

Comment: "He was the only one present."

Comment: _Nobbut_-Clefts being the forerunners of _Hobbut_-Holes is as likely as Tolkien's explanation of the origins of golf.

Comment: Would a reflexive sound more natural? i.e. himself/hisself.

Comment: To avoid using either, consider, "Nobody was present but/except for him."

Comment: This answer post might be helpful: [“Nobody but he/him was present”?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/57098/8758)

Comment: @Dog Lover: definitely not. There is no reflection suggested in the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody/None but he was present. - The use of "he", the subject pronoun is grammatically correct.

However, there may be more common alternatives:

He was the only one present. - As already brought up.

He was the sole attendee. - Depends on the context, say, conference, meeting, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody except him was present.

"ecxept" is a preposition and that is why "him" rather than "he" is used.  I would take "but" to be (in this instance) synonymous with "except", so it's a preposition and one uses "him".